# My first question was not well received and got 4 negative votes

Tags: discussion, specific-question

So I was wondering why [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52692110/can-you-have-an-html-elements-css-property-submit-a-form/52692317?noredirect=1#comment92321958_52692317) was so unwelcome... I have researched quite a bit, and I don't think it has been asked before.

I also tried to be as simple and clear as possible. Some understood the question without needing further explanation, while some demanded more and more clarity.

Comment: Do the comments not explain it? You haven't even stated what it is you are trying to do...which is a reason for downvoting.

Comment: `Some understood the question without needing further explanation, while some demanded more and more clarity.`  This answers your own question regarding the downvotes. People downvote for unclear questions.

Comment: You should not consider your title part of the body of the question. Either restate it, or provide a longer description of what you're actually trying to do. Also, try explaining _why_ you want to do this.

Comment: I understand that getting downvoted sucks, but do take a minute to think about what attracted you to this community in the first place. Was it the high-quality content? Well, guess what, downvotes are one of the primary tools that help us ensure that kind of quality...

Comment: Use title as a summary of your question. And everything must be in your question body. Here the usefull information are only in the title. Reading the question body make no sense.

Comment: Your question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: This is [specific-question], and it **is** possible to answer it reasonably, and it's not too terrible, I think it should not be closed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Contrary to what others have said in the comments, I don't think there's any disconnect between the title and body of your question. I don't think your question has any editorial issues, besides maybe "how can it be done?" being a little vague, but your example *does* illustrate your intention and tie your question title to the rest of it just fine IMO.

I think the main problem with your question is that it's based on a seemingly illogical premise, which is why it's so difficult for some readers to understand. This is often met with knee-jerk reactions as people (myself included, admittedly) do get frustrated and upset when confronted with something that "doesn't make sense". Your question is not the first of its kind to have had such a reception either. I don't have any suggestions off the top of my head what readers can do to alleviate this, but this is something I've observed a lot on the site and lament (especially given I've been part of the problem before).

I actually came across your question before you posted here; I left a comment under the answer which I'll quote here:

> background-attachment is an abstract concept. What you see is the background image itself, not whatever its background-attachment property is. You can't click on something that's abstract. To cite another (HTML, but similar in principle) example, you can't click on an element's ID - you can only click on the element itself that has that ID. Similarly, you can call a person by their name, but you're interacting with the person, not their name.

With this, as well as Quentin's comment,

> Are you trying to ask "How can I use an image as a button that the user can click on to submit a form? And can I make that image a background image instead of a content image"?

in mind, I believe your question could use some clarification. But as I don't wish to risk putting words in your mouth, I submit that you're in the best position to edit your question to clarify.

Comment: That explains a lot :) And in fact it solves the question I asked. I will also clarify the question further for future readers. Thank you.